# Global variables not being accessed, code not being ran

Tags: javascript

First post, sorry if i'm doing this wrong.

```
var tierArray = [390, 520, 750, 975, 1350, 1820, 3250];
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var rp;
var skinName = document.getElementById("skinName");
var skinRP = document.getElementById("skinRP");
var totalRP = document.getElementById("totalRP");
var totalMG = document.getElementById("totalMG");
var total = parseInt(totalRP.value);
var mg = parseInt(totalMG.value);

var array390, array520, array750, array975, array1350, array1820, array3250 = [];
var skinImg = document.getElementById("skin");
var activeArray;

function roll() {
    mg += 490;
    rp = tierArray[rand];
    total += rp;

    skinName.value = "hello";
    skinRP.value = rp;
    totalRP.value = total;
    totalMG.value = mg;
}
```

My page worked before moving all my variables to a global scope so that they were usable to other methods, now they have been moved the code doesn't run, and my JSLint is not picking up a problem, am i missing something?

Comment: what is the error in browser console?

Comment: What problem is JSLint picking up? And try to debug the script first to diagnose the problem. At first glance your script appears OK

Comment: were your variables earlier in global scope? what is error you are getting now?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you're not finding the elements using `getElementById` because this code is now running during page load before those elements are available, whereas before it wasn't until the `roll` function was called at some later point.  See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) for more information.

Comment: `document.getElementById("totalRP")` can return you a `null`, in this case `totalRP.value` will throw error

Comment: James Thorpe is right, and so is zooblin. Now can anyone help me to fix these problems? i need them to be global but do not want them to be there on page load.

Comment: Its easy, put your <script> tag at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Add your code in a document ready method. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the) is a nice explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements outside the functions are not loaded as you run your code, that probably is because you first implement your script to your page, and thén you insert your HTML DOM Elements.

```
<head>
<script>         < The elements dont exist
<body>
<element>        < The elements exist
<script>         < Your script
```

Comment: Thank you, i feel so stupid for getting this simple thing mixed up, never again now, cheers.